# Is it possible to Copy External List item Directly to Custom list

Tags: 2013, custom-list, external-list

I want to know whether I can copy External List items directly into Custom list in SharePoint 2013. also I want to know whether I can convert Text Field from External List to Person or Group field.

Comment: Do you want to copy programmatically or manually?

Comment: Programatically with timer job

Comment: You can use server object model to copy data from one list to another. What is the issue in this approach?

Comment: I din tried yet. Just wondering if its possible for External list .if yes than I would proceed. Also I want the field to be person in custom list which is Text field in External list

Answer (score 0):

In you custom Timer job, You can read the data from external list and create that other list with person column and while udpating You can convert that text value to SPUser object and add the listItem.